# stacking multiple Access fields into a label & a data field

Tags: ms-access, stack, field, stacked

I have a table that looks like this:
[oldTab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E16ZE.jpg)
I'd like to create a table that looks like this:
[newTab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66iXE.jpg)

I can run only the first line of this query: -

`INSERT INTO newTab (PairID, Code) SELECT PairID, MaleCode FROM oldTab`

`INSERT INTO newTab (PairID, Code) SELECT PairID, FemaleCode FROM oldTab`

With the addition of the second giving "*Syntax error in FROM clause.*"

I suspect I'm missing some assumed, basic SQL syntax, as am very much a beginner. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong or missing out?

Many thanks :-)

Comment: MS Access support only one query to execute at once (for multiple need vba macro). It doesn't support multiple query to run in one go like MSSQL, Oracle or other DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Access SQL, you need *two* queries.

First execute:

```
INSERT INTO newTab (PairID, Code) SELECT PairID, MaleCode FROM oldTab
```

Next, execute:

```
INSERT INTO newTab (PairID, Code) SELECT PairID, FemaleCode FROM oldTab
```

Comment: That great - many thanks :-)